# How to enter the following number to InputDialog form?

Tags: syntax, inputfield, input-forms

Consider some input field:

```
number = 
 DialogInput[{number = ""}, 
  Column[{"Enter the number", InputField[Dynamic[number], Number], 
    Button["Proceed", DialogReturn[number], ImageSize -> Automatic]}]]
```

It is not possible to enter any non-numeric symbol like `*` or `^`. In particular, it is not possible to enter large numbers, e.g. `2*10^20`, or `2e20`. Could you please tell me how to change DialogInput to allow such numbers?

One option would be change `Number` to `String`, and later add `ToExpression`. But it seems to me that it is not optimal, and potentially may lead to bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the default type of "Expression" for the input field. To eliminate the empty string in the input field, you can set the initial value to: Null.

Here is an example:

number =

```
 DialogInput[{number = Null}, 
  Column[{"Enter the number", InputField[Dynamic[number]], 
    Button["Proceed", DialogReturn[number], ImageSize -> Automatic]}]]
```

[image]

Now with some input:

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
200 \[Pi]
```